# jQuery EasySlider 1.7

Tags: jquery, easyslider

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can't get the slider to work. Images just stack on top of each other. I'm new to this. Any information or instructions would be helpful.

Thanks

```
<head>

    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/screen.css" media="screen" />
    <link href="css/css3menu1/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $("#slider").easySlider({
                auto: true, 
                continuous: true
            });
        }); 
    </script>

    </div>
    <div id="slider">
        <ul>    
            <li><img src="images/01.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/02.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/03.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/04.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/05.jpg" /></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="socialicons">
```

Comment: there's a missing </head> and <body>, to start with. either put all the code or provide a link

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery *before* you include the slider plugin.

Comment: You need to place the line `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>` before the line `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>` in your code.

Comment: thanks, sorted now, can I hide these images when editing in dreamweaver, they seem to stack above each other down the page ?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Dreamweaver, sorry. By the way, if you found my answer helpful, consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks.